# coredns running status but not become ready

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I have a k8s cluster with three masters, two workers, and an external haproxy and use flannel as a cni.
The coredns have problems, and their status is running, but they don't become ready.

Coredns log

[image: 1]

I get the logs of this pod, and I get this message:

> [INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "Kubernetes."

What I do to solve this problem but didn't get any result:
1- check ufw and disable it.
2- check IPtables and flush them.
3- check Kube-proxy logs.
4- check the haproxy, and it is accessible from out and all servers in the cluster.
5- check nodes network.
7- reboot all servers at the end. :))

I get describe po :

[describe pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S5ux.png)

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to general k8s infrastructure, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You missed providing `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` in the question and hoping random folks over the internet to guess the problem with your pod.

Comment: Thank you.I add the picture of the out put of `kubectl describe pod <pod-name> `.  
@P....

Comment: The error you have shared in the `kubectl describe` shows that your readiness probe is failing with error code 503(`the server is not ready to handle the request`). You will be able to find more info when you will do `kubectl logs <pod-name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem.
It didn't relate to coredns. It was about the IPtables rule.
Some rules for Kubernetes svc did not create.
Now with the rules which are in the picture, everything is okay:

[iptables rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th0mD.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### Lets see your CoreDNS works at all?

- You can crete a simple pod and go inside and from there, curl Services via `IP:PORT` & `Service-name:PORT`

  ```bash
  kubectl run -it --rm test-nginx-svc --image=nginx  -- bash
  ```

1. IP:PORT

   ```bash
   curl http://<SERVICE-IP>:8080
   ```
2. DNS

   ```bash
   curl http://nginx-service:8080
   ```

If you couldn't curl your service via `Service-name:PORT` then you probably have a DNS Issue....

---

##### CoreDNS

Service Name Resolution Problems?

- Check CoreDNS Pods are running and accessible?
- Check CoreDNS logs

```bash
kubectl run -it test-nginx-svc --image=nginx -- bash
```

- Inside the Pod

  ```bash
  cat /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- The result would look like:

  ```
  nameserver 10.96.0.10 # IP address of CoreDNS
  search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
  options ndots:5
  ```

---

#### If It is NOT working:

I suggest to try re-install it via [official docs](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel) or [helm chart](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/issues/1426)

OR

Try onther CNIs like [weave](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/)

---

[Source](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#coredns)